# Eclipse on windows 8.1 doesn't find my google nexus

Tags: android, eclipse, windows-8.1

I'm running windows 8.1 and having a Google Nexus S as Android device.

Debug mode is enabled and I can add/delete files on the device so windows recognizes the device. When I want to compile and run my Android program eclipse says "No compatible targets found."

Can someone help me? I also did a factory reset and rebooted my pc.

Answer (score 0):

Factory reset generally means, that USB debugging is turned off again. Turn that on and check once again.

Comment: Doesn't work, I've turned it on again. When I connect the phone to my windows 7 laptop it works like a charm so nothing is wrong with the phone. Is there something I need to do under windows 8?

Answer (score 0):

You need to plug in the device then go the device manager in windows. Uninstall the driver of the google phone. Then install it again but point to the Android SDK delivered drivers. Thats it.